# How can I fix file permissions (and owner/group) so that files uploaded by php can be deleted?

Tags: php, file, permissions, upload

I have a script that uploads files to a directory with file permissions 0644. I am unable to delete the file via FTP or using PHP's unlink() function (550 error). After scouring the web, I was unable to find a method to fix this problem. I am aware that the issue has to do with group/owner permissions, but I don't know how to fix the problem.

Should I use copy() or rename() instead?

Any ideas?

**Edit:** All uploaded files have owner/group set as: 48 48. All other files that I have uploaded via FTP and NOT the PHP script are 1006 1006. Is the owner/group set for the incorrect user?
I have already tried using chmod() to set permissions to 0666. I think the problem may be with the user?

**Edit 2:** Should I use exec() and run a command that changes the owner and group of the file?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what user your script is running as. Try uploading the files as `0655` instead

Comment: @alienwebguy I tried 0655 but it doesn't work. I added some more info in the question.

Comment: My guess then is that you need to up the permissions of the directory containing the file.

Comment: @alienwebguy, they are already set to 0777. Do all parent directories need these permissions?

Comment: Recursively to the doc root, all parent directories need write permissions for your script, but 0777 allows groups to execute files which is a big no no. Try chmod 1775 /controlled for your directories.

Comment: @alienwebguy Sadly, this did not work. I'm almost certain that chmod permissions are not the issue here. I'm trying figure out how to change owner and group via exec()

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `move_uploaded_file();` function, permissions are set correctly, so unlink(); should work

try this

```
move_uploaded_file($from, $to);
chmod($to, 0666);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to have write permission to delete the file. 6 represents read/write. The first number after the zero represents the file's owner, who created it. If you are running the script to create the file, you should be able to delete it as long as you use the same user, probably the server user.